# Code Pipeline not able to create Layers in Lambda using sam template

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I have below sam template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing lambda 1 function.
Resources:
  awstransformedcurlambdafn:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: .
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 300
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/Role1'
      Tracing: Active
  transformedcurNodeModulesLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: layer-lambda1
      Description: layers with log4js library
      ContentUri: ./layers/nodejs/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
      LicenseInfo: 'Available under the MIT-0 license.'
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Now in my layers folder consist all the node js packages

Folder structure.

layers ----> nodejs ---> package.json & node_modules --> log4j ....

Now After run code pipeline it got success but saw that there no layers created but sam template deployed successfully even my new codes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see based on the code above, Layers option is not set in the function resource

```
Resources:
  awstransformedcurlambdafn:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: .
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 300
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/Role1'
      Tracing: Active
      Layers:
        - !Ref transformedcurNodeModulesLayer
  transformedcurNodeModulesLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: layer-lambda1
      Description: layers with log4js library
      ContentUri: ./layers/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
      LicenseInfo: 'Available under the MIT-0 license.'
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Can you please try adding above property in your "awstransformedcurlambdafn" function resource?

Comment: It is just reference a layer but that layer is not at all created

Comment: I meant that Layer option was missing in the function resource, i have completed the snippet to avoid confusion and also ContentUri in layer resource should be top level of dependency folder i.e. ./layers/ and not ./layers/nodejs/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/